# How to move buttons from column to row?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a question. I have buttons below a post and they are located in a column. How to move buttons to a row instead of a column?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def shop(ctx):
    data = db.get_info(ctx.author.id)
    msg = await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Choose a product which the you want buy!\n\n{zpcoin} Мой баланс: {data['ZPCoin']}",
    delete_after=60,
        components = 
        [
             [
                    Button(style = ButtonStyle.grey, label = '50 ZPCoins = 25.000$', emoji='', custom_id='product1'),                  
                    Button(style = ButtonStyle.grey, emoji='', label = '100 ZP Coins = 10.000$', custom_id='product2')
             ]
        ])
    response = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if response.component.custom_id == 'product1':
        await msg.delete()
        if data['ZPCoin'] >= 50:
         await response.send(f'You bought product 25.000$ in price {zpcoin} 50 ZPCoins!', delete_after=30)
         db.save_substract_zp_coins(ctx.author.id, 50)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You miss {zpcoin} {50-data['ZPCoin']} ZP Coins on buy a this product!", delete_after=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to separate them into two actionrows instead of one

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def shop(ctx):
    data = db.get_info(ctx.author.id)
    msg = await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Choose a product which the you want buy!\n\n{zpcoin} Мой баланс: {data['ZPCoin']}",
    delete_after=60,
        components = 
        [
             [
                    Button(style = ButtonStyle.grey, label = '50 ZPCoins = 25.000$', emoji='', custom_id='product1')],
             [                  
                    Button(style = ButtonStyle.grey, emoji='', label = '100 ZP Coins = 10.000$', custom_id='product2')
             ]
        ])
    response = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
    if response.component.custom_id == 'product1':
        await msg.delete()
        if data['ZPCoin'] >= 50:
         await response.send(f'You bought product 25.000$ in price {zpcoin} 50 ZPCoins!', delete_after=30)
         db.save_substract_zp_coins(ctx.author.id, 50)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You miss {zpcoin} {50-data['ZPCoin']} ZP Coins on buy a this product!", delete_after=30)```
````

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: discord_components isn't maintained anymore. So you should consider switching to a maintained package, but I will edit my answer

Comment: Well, this module does not prevent me from bad ones, it works stably, which is good.

Comment: Sure, just saying. In case my answer help feel free to upvote and mark them as accepted answer. :)

Comment: Found this answer via a Google Search. This solved my problem with trying to figure out how to organize buttons on different rows. I needed to make lists in my components list. Thank you! +1